# sed double conditional? Match start of line, containing text, then append

Tags: sed

I have a config file I'm trying to edit in a script, there are several lines, but the format is basically:

```
...
admin_users = alice, bob
admin_groups = accounting, finance
...
```

I would like to append a user to the admin_users line if they don't already exist on that line.

As I understand it, I'll need to basically combine two conditionals...

`/^admin_users/s/$/, charlie/` = Add `, charlie` to lines beginning with `admin_users`
`/charlie/!s/$/, charlie/` = Append `, charlie` to lines not containing `charlie`

I've tried googling around but I can't find anything relevant. If this is possible, the syntax and then a short explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To catch more special cases, let's use this test file:

```
$ cat file
...
admin_users = alice, bob
admin_users = alice, charlieston
admin_users = alice, charlie, bob
admin_users = alice, bob, charlie
admin_groups = accounting, finance
...
```

In sum, the first two `admin_users` need to have `charlie` added.  The second two already have him.

To add `charlie` only if he is not already there:

```
$ sed -r '/^admin_users .*, charlie(,|$)/{p;d}; /^admin_users / s/$/, charlie/' file
...
admin_users = alice, bob, charlie
admin_users = alice, charlieston, charlie
admin_users = alice, charlie, bob
admin_users = alice, bob, charlie
admin_groups = accounting, finance
...
```

#### How it works

- `-r`

  Use extended, rather than basic, regular expressions.  (On OSX/BSD, use `-E` instead.)
- `/^admin_users .*, charlie(,|$)/{p;d}`

  If an `admin_users` already has `charlie` followed by either a comma or the end of the line, then print,`p`, it as is and delete, `d`, it so that no further commands are applied to it.
- `/^admin_users / s/$/, charlie/`

  If we get to here, that means that `charlie` is not already on the line.  Thus, we add `charlie` to the end.

#### Mac OSX

The above was tested on GNU `sed`.  For OSX/BSD `sed`, try:

```
sed -E -e '/^admin_users .*, charlie(,|$)/{p;d;}' -e '/^admin_users / s/$/, charlie/' file
```

#### A Variation

As suggested by [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman), here is another approach:

```
sed '/^admin_users\>/ {/\<charlie\>/! s/$/, charlie/}' file
```

This selects lines thta start with `admin_users` and then, only if the line does not contain `charlie`, a substitution is made.  `\<` and `\>` are regex expressions meaning the beginning or ending of a word.  They are supported by at least GNU sed.

Comment: A little simpler: `sed '/^admin_users\>/ {/\<charlie\>/! s/$/, charlie/}'` -- BSD validity left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Having GNU `sed` I would use this:

```
sed '/^admin_users/{/\bcharlie\b/!s/$/, charlie/}' input
```

**Explanation:**

`/^admin_users/` searches for lines starting with `admin_users` and applies the following block between curly braces `{}` to that line. `/\bcharlie\b/!` checks that the line does not contain the word `charlie`. Note the word boundaries `\b` which makes sure `charlie2` or `bigcharlie` wouldn't match.

If it is sure that the line does not contain the term charlie, the `s/$/, charlie` command appends `, charlie` to the end of the line `$`.

---

On MacOS the `\b` for the word boundaries will not work. You need to use `[[:<:]]` for the left boundary and `[[:>:]]` for the right boundary. The command would look like:

```
sed '/^admin_users/{/[[:<:]]charlie[[:>:]]/!s/$/, charlie/}' input
```